# Eclipse (find and replace): Make < System.out.println("x") > to < Logger.log("x", Level.Info) >

Tags: eclipse

I have an huge old software project that I want to integrate in my own. For that, I want to replace all

```
System.out.println("x")
```

with

```
Logger.log("x", Level.Info)
```

How can I do this with Eclipse?

edit:

e.g.:

```
System.out.println("x") --> Logger.log("x", Level.Info)
System.out.println("abc") --> Logger.log("abc", Level.Info)
System.out.println(myObject) --> Logger.log(myObject, Level.Info)
```

I want to to it with one command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse supports a multi file search and replace approach incl. preview:

1. Main Menu -> Search -> File...
2. Input the following as "Containing text": System.out.println(("[^"]*"))
3. Check Regular Expression Checkbox
4. Choose the scope (Workspace, Project etc.)
5. Hit Replace...
6. When asked input the following as "With": Logger.log(\1, Level.Info)
7. Leave Regular Expression Checkbox checked
8. Hit Preview... and inspect ALL changes (see warning below)
9. Hit ok to accept changes

This is a very simple method using the expression "[^"]*" to match exactly two quotes and everything between. If the texts in your program are more complex this approach has to be adjusted accordingly, e.g. the following doesn't work using "[^"]*"

```
System.out.println("x"+"y");
System.out.println("x"+2);
System.out.println("x:\"3\"");
```

Please use this wisely.

Comment: nice! thanx! just two back-slash have been missing to escape the ( and ): System.out.println\(("[^"]*")\)

Comment: could it be that the back-slashes are removed? \(

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to replace `System.out.println("random text here");` with `Logger.log("same random text here",Level.info);`. I don't think that's possible in Eclipse, but you can do a small Java prgram, that reads all the *.java files from your project, does the replacement and then re-outputts them, something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String source = "System.out.println(\"text\");";
        String sourcePrefix = "System.out.println(\"";
        String sourceSuffix = "\");";
        String targetPrefix = "Logger.log(\"";
        String targetSuffix = "\",LogLevel.info);";

        String replaced = source.replace(sourcePrefix, targetPrefix).replace(sourceSuffix, targetSuffix);
        System.out.println(replaced);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a text replacement, like you suggested, but there also is the possibility to redirect the System.out entirely using something like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("stdout");                                   
LoggingOutputStream los = new LoggingOutputStream(logger, StdOutErrLevel.STDOUT);          
System.setOut(new PrintStream(los, true));
```